# automatize the har file generation from google chrome and automatizing collecting and showing them in the mail

Tags: google-chrome, automation, har

what i need to realize is a way of automatizing opening google chrome and analyzing the network waterfall from the google developer tool

1. open the google chrome
2. open the google developer tool
3. load one url
4. navigate the url,and export all the waterfall out
5. record the total time of the whole website loading, and show all the waterfall of the network.
6. cycle above and collect the url and according total url loading and waterfall and show them in one mail.

anyone idea? help me

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to do this in Chrome, but using NetExport in Firefox does most of what you're looking  for:

http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/netexport/

You can auto-export the HAR file, or you can manually copy the waterfall as an image, which you could then paste into an email.